# Shared memory C questions(size,structures

Tags: c, shared-memory, shared

So im new to C and I've got some questions about shared memory.

Im using different .c to use the shm.

This is the program where i create the memory

```
int id = shmget( 1234, CONSTANT*sizeof(structure),IPC_CREAT | 0666 );
exit_on_error (id, "Error");
```

SO my question is how in another program can I acess this memory and know that "CONSTANT"

I have something like this

```
int id = shmget(1234, 0,0);
exit_on_error (id, "Error");

*/structure pointer*/ sp = (structure*) shmat(id,0,0);
exit_on_null (structure pointer,"Error");
```

But now I need that constant in order to iterate on the number of "objects" of the structure and edit the objects

Comment: Maybe you could add sizeof(size_t) to your allocation size. Use these extra-bytes and place the value of CONSTANT at the beginning of the shared memory buffer, then you can read it on the other process and proceed with your iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function, *shmctl()* which takes a command, *IPC_STAT*, and fills in a structure *shmid_ds* which describes the object.